# Resistance of JFET when used as a voltage controlled resistor

Tags: impedance, jfet, eeg

We have designed a circuit for a bidirectional current limiter using an N-channel JFET as below:

[image]

This limiter is connected to the end of electrode used for EEG measurement.

The requirement for the product is to measure the skin to electrode impedance also.

Idea behind using the circuit was, the current from the current source would pass through resistor R13 which would generate a negative potential at V(G-S).

This in turn will control the amount of current flowing through the circuit.

The current input is in the range of uA. Typically 6uA.

For testing purpose we connect a resistance ranging from 1k to 330k so as to simulate the skin to electrode impedance.

During testing I found that the resistance of the JFET is non-linear for different temperature ranges.

Due to this, the error in calculating the actual impedance is more than 25%.

Can anyone please help with ways to reduce the temperature based non-linearity of the JFET, or else, a circuit which would limit current bidirectionally to about 80uA?

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is *about* 80 μA, I wouldn't bother doing it manually and just use the ever-handy [REF200](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ref200.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1624991912115) from TI (formerly Burr-Brown). The IC contains two 100 μA current sources and a current mirror, but all you need is one of the current sources in conjunction with four diodes (or both of the current sources along with two diodes) to create a bidirectional 100 μA current limiter. (see figure 17 in the datasheet.)

The current sources inside the chip are internally compensated for low temperature coefficient (datasheet claims 25 ppm/°C typical), so you shouldn't have to worry much about that. The variation of current with temperature is nonlinear, however (figure 1), so be aware of that if you do need to account for the few hundred nanoamps of temperature drift.

The price may be a downside. At about [$10 each](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/texas-instruments/REF200AU/251209) in single quantity, it's far from the cheapest method of doing what you need--but it may well be among the easiest.

Also be aware that this method is limited to 40 volts of compliance voltage; above that point, you're exceeding the part's limits and it likely won't survive.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply @Hearth. I guess there is a confusion or some data is missing in the question. Let me reiterate.

The 24 bit sigma delta ADC which we are using for EEG measurement has an internal current source which provides a current for different amplitude (6nA, 6uA, 24nA, 24uA). For our application, we found that 6uA of source current works well.

When this current passes through R13 as mentioned in the circuit diagram, there is a negative voltage on VGS which limits the current if it is more than 80uA because of any fault condition.
Contd..

Comment: I am facing problem due to the non linearity of the JFET.
Is there any method to reduce the non linearity over temperature?
Or else can you please suggest me a circuit for bidirectional current limiter which limits current more than 80uA?
The circuit need not have a current source as we are already using the IC's internal current source.

Comment: @Sushant A current source and a current limiter are exactly the same thing--what you are describing is exactly what the REF200 does.

Comment: I am not sure how a current source can be used in place of limiter.

Comment: @Sushant Just think of this as a current limiter then. That's what it is.

Comment: I cannot see if the current is user selectable. I'll still explore the IC. Thanks a lot for the answer

Comment: The figure 17 here is an example of reverse voltage protection. I am unable to understand how the current source which would be sourcing a current of 50uA (say)+the 6uA current that my IC will be sourcing will help limiting the current.

Comment: @Sushant The current is not user-selectable. You didn't say anything about needing it to be. This will only act to limit the current to no more than 100 μA.